# How to calculate the intensity profile of a pulsed laser beam given its pulse energy?

Tags: energy, waves, laser, intensity

I am trying to calculate the intensity profile of a pulsed laser given that the intensity envelope is Gaussian. I also know the full width half maximum and pulse energy of the pulse.

What are the relevant equations needed to calculate the intensity profile?

Comment: Temporal or spacial profile?

Comment: @OfekGillon temporal profile

Comment: So you know that $E(t) = E_0 \exp(-\frac{t^2}{2\tau^2}) $ and you want to know $E_0$ and $\tau$, right? Well, from plugging the FWHM you can get an equation for $\tau$, and by integrating the intensity you will get the energy density of the pulse, thus getting an equation for $E_0 $

Comment: @OfekGillon Is E energy or electric field amplitude?

Comment: What ever you want it to be, this statement will hold (with different parameters $\tau, E_0$) for both cases. You just need to know how to convert one to another :)

Comment: @OfekGillon Alright thanks.

Comment: @OfekGillon Turns out I had to calculate spatial profile too. Couold you perhaps guide me in the correct direction?

Comment: Well for that there is a whole wikipedia article :) 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107355/discussion-between-taenyfan-and-ofek-gillon).

Comment: Hey, I replied :)